# Marionette: Starting and stopping modules based on route regexp

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, routes, marionette

I'm implementing an application which has two separate submodules within top level application module.
I have an admin module with a convention for routes to start with `/admin` and user module having routes that start with `/user`. Top level application defines a `rootRoute` so that when you navigate to `http://url/` you are redirected to either admin or user page based on permissions. What i'm trying to understand is whether it is possible to start and stop specific modules based on the route. Here is an example of what i mean:

Let's assume i have a top level application (in coffeescript)

```
@ClientApp = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

  App = new Marionette.Application

  navigate: (route, options = {}) ->
    Backbone.history.navigate route, options

  App.on "start", (options) ->
    if Backbone.history
      Backbone.history.start()

  App.on "stop", ->
    App.module("AdminApp").stop()
    App.module("UserApp").stop()

  class App.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    initialize: (options) ->
      @route /^admin(.*)/, 'startAdminApp', options.controller.startAdminApp
      @route /^user(.*)/, 'startUserApp', options.controller.startUserApp

    appRoutes:
      "": "redirectToRoot"

  App.addInitializer ->
    new App.Router
      controller: API

  API =
    redirectToRoot: ->
      # some redirect logic that will lead you to either /admin or /user

    startAdminApp: ->
      App.mainRegion.show new App.Layouts.Admin
      App.module("AdminApp").start()

    startUserApp: ->
      App.mainRegion.show new App.Layouts.User
      App.module("UserApp").start()

  App
```

Inside admin and user submodules i also have defined routes

```
@ClientApp.module "AdminApp.DashboardApp", (DashboardApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  _.extend DashboardApp, Backbone.Wreqr.radio.channel("dashboard")

  class DashboardApp.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
      "admin/dashboard": "statistics"

  API =
    getLayout: ->
      new DashboardApp.Layout.View

    statistics: ->
      DashboardApp.StatisticsAp.start()

  DashboardApp.on "start", ->
    @layout = API.getLayout().render()
    API.statistics()

  App.addInitializer ->
    new DashboardApp.Router
      controller: API
```

If i navigate to `/` the application works as expected, i'm redirected to necessary namespace and a specific sub-module is started. However if i define some other routes within a submodule, they seem to override the existing regexp matchers. So if i open the browser and navigate to `/admin/statistics` it will not start the admin application and the callback for `/admin/statistics` will fail with error. That is because the admin application won't start and the mainRegion is not filled with a corresponding layout. Note that the file containing top level application definition is required before any of the submodules (i guess that is why routes are overridden). I also understand that backbone router will invoke route callback when the first match is met.

So the question is whether it's possible to implement a kind of route manager that will check current route with a regular expression and start or stop the corresponding application (either admin or user) with all defined sub-routes being persistent and bookmarkable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had close task to resolve, haven't found any existing solution, so here is a [small stub - project](https://github.com/jeka1985/marionette-require-stack) i've created

To resolve such task there are few problems to resolve :

1) Async routing. something like `rootRouter` should load app module and `moduleRouter` should call controller methods

2) Clear up backbone history handlers on module stop. The problem is even after module stop, route and handler still exist in BB history

So my hack, i mean solution :)

We need some router that will watch URL change and load module, Let it be `ModuleManager`

```
define(
    [
        'application'
    ],
    function(App) {

        App.module('ModuleManager', function(ModuleManager, Application, Backbone, Marionette) {

            var currentPageModule = false,
                stopModule = function(name) {
                    name && Application.module(name).stop();
                },
                startModule = function(name) {
                    Application.module(name).start();
                };

            ModuleManager.getModuleNameByUrl = function() {
                var name = Backbone.history.getHash().split('/')[0];
                return name ? (name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1)) : 'Home'
            };

            ModuleManager.switchModule = function(name) {

                if (!name) return;

                stopModule(currentPageModule);
                startModule(name);

                currentPageModule = name;

            };

            ModuleManager.requireModule = function(name, callback) {
                require(['apps/pages/' + name + '/index'],
                    callback.bind(this),
                    function() {
                        require(['apps/pages/404/index'], function() {
                            ModuleManager.switchModule('404');
                        })
                    }
                );
            };
            /*
            * this is key feature - we should catch all routes
            * and load module by url path
            */
            ModuleManager.FrontRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

                routes: {
                    '*any': 'loadModule'
                },

                loadModule: function() {
                    var name = ModuleManager.getModuleNameByUrl();

                    ModuleManager.requireModule(name, function() {
                        ModuleManager.switchModule(name);
                    })
                }
            });

            ModuleManager.addInitializer(function() {
                new ModuleManager.FrontRouter;
            });

            ModuleManager.addFinalizer(function() {
                delete ModuleManager.FrontRouter;
            });
        });
    }
);
```

Great, that will load module with routes inside. But we'll get another problem - on sub module start we init its router, but we already routed to the page on sub-router init and URL still same. So sub-router will not be invoked till next navigation. So we need special router, that will handle such situation. Here is 'ModuleRouter':

```
App.ModuleRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({

    forceInvokeRouteHandler: function(routeRegexp, routeStr, callback) {
        if(routeRegexp.test(Backbone.history.getHash()) ) {
            this.execute(callback, this._extractParameters(routeRegexp, routeStr));
        }
    },

    route: function(route, name, callback) {

        var routeString = route,
            router = this;

        if (!_.isRegExp(route)) route = this._routeToRegExp(route);

        if (_.isFunction(name)) {
            callback = name;
            name = '';
        }

        if (!callback) callback = this[name];

        // проблема - RouterManager уже стригерил событие route, загрузил саб-роутер.
        // при создании саб роутера его колбэк уже вызван не будет, поскольку адрес страницы не изменился
        // при добавлении роутов используется нативный ВВ route - который вещает колбэк на указанный фрагмент
        // расширяем - если мы уже находимся на фрагменте на который устанавливается колбэк - принудительно вызвать
        // выполнение обработчика совпадения фрагмента

        /*
        * PROBLEM : AppsManager already triggered 'route' and page fragments still same,
        * so module router will not be checked on URL matching.
        *
        * SOLUTION : updated route method, add route to Backbone.history as usual, but also check if current page
        * fragment match any appRoute and call controller callback
        * */

        this.forceInvokeRouteHandler(route, routeString, callback);

            Backbone.history.route(route, function(fragment) {
                var args = router._extractParameters(route, fragment);

                router.execute(callback, args);
                router.trigger.apply(router, ['route:' + name].concat(args));
                router.trigger('route', name, args);

                Backbone.history.trigger('route', router, name, args);
            });

            return this;
        },
        // implementation destroy method removing own handlers anr routes from backbone history
        destroy: function() {

            var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
                routKeys = _.keys(this.appRoutes).map(function(route) {
                    return this._routeToRegExp(route).toString();
                }.bind(this));

            Backbone.history.handlers = Backbone.history.handlers.reduce(function(memo, handler) {
                _.indexOf(routKeys, handler.route.toString()) < 0  && memo.push(handler)

                return memo;
            }, []);

            Marionette.triggerMethod.apply(this, ['before:destroy'].concat(args));
            Marionette.triggerMethod.apply(this, ['destroy'].concat(args));

            this.stopListening();
            this.off();

            return this;
    }
})
```

Please fill free to ask question or chat, i guess there are some point might need to be clarified.

Comment: Hi @Evgeniy
You can't even imagine how you helped me. I was thinking of a similar approach and ended up with a working solution based on the code you've provided. Many thanks to you. That was a very good and self explanatory example.